# Can I pass a variable from my javascript to a jsp file?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, liferay

I have a variable that I create in javascript in a html file. (I cannot create this anywhere else) The variable is an array, with two entries. A latitude and a longitude. I was hoping to use ajax to send these variable and then use them in my jsp file. There I want to fill in a form with this var.

Anyone know of a way to do this? I'm working with java 1.8

Comment: why not immediately put this javascript in the jsp file

Comment: Ajax is the way to go here.

Comment: @Stultuske How can I do that? Can you point me to some documentation on that?

Comment: the very same way you did put it in your html file.

Comment: "I was hoping to use ajax to send these variable and then use them in my jsp file."  Do you have a servlet that accepts the ajax post already?  If you do, then you can attach the variable to the HTTP session on the server, and then access the session variable in your JSP file.

Comment: @Stultuske I'm using aui tags, but my javascript can't find them based on id? Could that be because of the aui tags?

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer. Do not edit the question

Answer (score 0):

The JSP is compiled at server and rendered as HTML in browser.
At browser, there is not JSP left. It is already being converted to HTML and(JS , CSS).

Only way to do that is to pass parameter back to server in separate request.

Post `form` to new jsp or same jsp.